# Rewrite, add tail to the domain via .htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am trying to rewrite wp .htaccess file from http://example.com to http://example.com/en

I've tried to add this code below the RewriteBase:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it added several times "/en" in the tail

The head code of the current .htaccess file is this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
```

I expect to adding only once "/en", and if end with "/en" to not adding anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
           RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en [L,R=301]
```

What you did was actually just right.